# Full image adapter error

Tags: java, android

I have a custom base image adapter in which i use for a grid view.. i was trying to use it for a full image view but i get an error while creating the my custom adapter object...passing the parameters....
By the way sorry for any mistakes ,this is my first question:
This is for gallery to preview full

Fullimage java:Where the error is present

```
public class FullImage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

        Intent i= getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        MyPicsAdapter adapter = new MyPicsAdapter(this);//ERROR is here!!!

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        imageView.setImageResource(adapter.item_image[position]);

    }
}
```

Custom Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyPicsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public Context context;
    public final int item_image[];
    public final String item_text[];

    public MyPicsAdapter(Context context, int item_image[], String[] item_text)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.item_image = item_image;
        this.item_text = item_text;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from custom_gridview.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview, null);

            // set value into imageview
            ImageView image = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            image.setImageResource(item_image[position]);

            // set value into textview
            TextView text = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            text.setText(item_text[position]);
        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item_text.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Class where the images are:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Smitpic extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView grid;
    String text[] = {
            "Colorful countryside on the way to Smit",
            "A local bus at the Village square",
            "Cattle grazing at the village ground",
            "Pine trees lined the road leading to the Wooden house",
            "Traditional wooden house made without any metal nails",
            "Intricate carvings on the door of the wooden house",
            "A cottage at Smit",
            "Villagers returning home after washing clothes at the river",
            "A river idlying flowing near Smit",
            "Colorful field of grasses and pine trees"
    };
    int image[] = {R.drawable.smit1,R.drawable.smit2,
            R.drawable.smit3,R.drawable.smit4,R.drawable.smit5,
            R.drawable.smit6,R.drawable.smit7,R.drawable.smit8,
            R.drawable.smit9,R.drawable.smit10
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smitpic);

        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.simpleGrid);
        grid.setAdapter(new MyPicsAdapter(this,image,text));
        // grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,image));

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent a= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullImage.class);
                a.putExtra("id",position);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the specific error you are facing...can you show the logcat ?

Comment: Passing id is not really enough you will have to pass image as well as text via intent to next activity.

Comment: its the line here  MyPicsAdapter adapter = new MyPicsAdapter(this); (this)-gets and error saying :    Error:(22, 33) error: constructor MyPicsAdapter in class MyPicsAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,int[],String[]
found: FullImage
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: above MyPicsAdapter  needs three arguments.

Comment: I only need to pass the images from the adapter .can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass only the image as follows,

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullImage.class);
        a.putExtra("id", image[position]);
        startActivity(a);
    }
});
```

Inside `onCreate` of `FullImage` Activity get the image and display it in the `ImageView`,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

    int image = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
}
```